# Limiting `declarative_net_request` rules to subdomain in Chrome Extension manifest version 3

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

In Manifest V3 Chrome's team introduced [declarativeNetRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/declarativeNetRequest/). We can't seem to make sure those rules are applied only to sites of a certain domain:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "priority": 1,
        "action": {
            "type": "block"
        },
        "condition": {
            "urlFilter": "main.js",
            "resourceTypes": ["script"]
        }
    }
]
```

We defined, those rules are fired in every webpage you visit. Can we filter the rules by this host of rule and not by the destination of the script? We couldn't find indication for it in the docs or the [examples](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/declarativeNetRequest/#example).

Needless to say any off-docs improvisation in the `manifest.json` failed to leave a mark. For instance:

```
{
...
 "declarative_net_request": {
        "matches": ["https://SUB_DOMAIN_NAME.domain.com/*"],  <====== this
        "rule_resources": [
            {
                "id": "ruleset_1",
                "enabled": true,
                "path": "rules.json"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like `domains`, I see it in the first example :-)

Comment: Yes, this will filter requests made *to* the specified domain not from the current tab domain, afaics.

Comment: My confusing, you seem to be right, yes, i dont know how i missed it :)